# MySQL query help needed please

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `air_video` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` DATE NOT NULL,
`time` TIME NOT NULL,
`asset_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`duration` TIME NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There are entries with the same `asset_id`, `duration` and `name`, but different `date` and `time`. These are same videos that were aired multiple times during some time.

I need to calculate total `duration` for distinct videos grouped by each month. 
Please give some ideas?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+group+by+month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need the sum of the duration of each distinct video per month:

```
select
  year,
  month,
  sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(duration))) as totaltime
from
  (select distinct
    av.asset_id,
    av.duration,
    year(av.date) as year,  
    month(av.date) as month
  from
    air_video av)
group by
  year,
  month
```

<strike>So you'll need the `sum` of durations, `grouped` per video per month...</strike>

Smart use of grouping as suggested by RobertHarvey in the comments (thanks).
`time_to_sec` is used to convert a time value to seconds so it can be summed.

```
select
  av.asset_id,
  year(av.date) as year,  
  month(av.date) as month,
  sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(av.duration))) as totaltime
from
  air_video av
group by
  av.asset_id,
  year(av.date), 
  month(av.date)
```

Comment: GolezTrol, thanks for you anwser. But I need one line per month with sum of unique video durations for this month. For example I have data for 10 months in my table - I need to get 10 lines with total duration of unique videos for each month. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean, you need a single row per month, where you get the sum of all video's played that month, but counting each distinct video only once?

Comment: Okay, see my modified answer.

Comment: And if it's possible - an average daily duration of distinct videos for each month.

Comment: OK, got to go. Will try to figure it out myself. Thanks a lot, GolezTrol!